# Appium negative test case

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium-android

I'm trying to test a negative case via Appium for an Android application. On unsuccessful login, it shows a toast message, need to assert the toast value/message. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

**UIAutomator2** supports finding toast messages, so you you need to set it in desired capabilities like:

`automationName`: `UIAutomator2`

and then you can search for it like any other element. If you are using java-client, example is [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/UIAutomator2Test.java#L86)